# window screenshot's number recognition

Tags: java, ocr

I need to develop application for number recognition. 
My steps:
1) i find the needed window with table and take a screenshot
2) i take "blocks" of image (the block is cell of table)
3) i need to recognite a numbers inside cell (block).

so, i make 1 and 2 steps (take BufferedImage) but how can i recognite a numbers inside?

ps
I think tesseract (for example tess4j) is to large for this solution, or anyone dont think so?
The blocks a very small (for example 36x13 pix). The fonts are standart (tahoma or verdana).
sample image here:[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhH2K.png)

Regards!

Comment: Did you search Google for "OCR java"?

Comment: Yes, i found tess4j - now trying to using it. AspriseOCR, for example, cant recognite images correctly. I just want to know more "lite" solution not using fat libraryes. But if i will not find soulution then i must use tess4j

Comment: If you have some experience with artificial intelligence, you can make neural network for OCR, you have many tutorials on google how to make this.

Comment: As i think tesseract cant recognite my image becouse its size is too small :(

Comment: I solve it by resizing image. But have another problem. I need to smooth resizing but grph.scale gives to me a pixelized image and tesseract mistakes... So :) Another question is how to resize image with smooth

Comment: Tess4J has a `ImageHelper.getScaledInstance` method that you can try.